# Assign XML- AJAX response in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I have page in which data get extracted from xml. All works fine but I am not able to assign reply in HTML.

XML :

```
<XML>
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<sales>
<sales_list>
<id>123</id>
<outlet_name>vividham</outlet_name>
<sales_date>2015-05-22</sales_date>
<sales_time>20:45:00</sales_time>
</sales_list>
</sales>
</XML>
```

following is my js. -

```
var sales_date = $('#sales_date').val();

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:'http://www.xyz.co/AppData/sales_list.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {

                 var items = $(xml).find('sales_list').filter(function(){
                        return $('sales_date', this).text() == sales_date;
                     });

                items.each(function(index, sales_list){
                    var id = $(this).find('id').text();
                    var outlet_name = $(this).find('outlet_name').text();
                    var sales_time = $(this).find('sales_time').text();

                    // I am not able to assign data to html from here.                              

                });
            }


  });
```

HTML: -

```
<div class="list-block" id="sales_content">
    <ul>
        <li class="item-content" id="sales_list">
            <div class="item-media">here I need time</div>
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title">Here I need outlet_name</div>
            </div>
        </li>                           
    </ul>
</div>
```

`div` with sales_content will refresh on Button click refreshing inner `<ul>` content. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the XML you're trying to sort, and how you want it sorted? Maybe a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle) without the ajax stuff?

Comment: I have added XML content

Comment: on what `xml` attribute you want to sort??

Comment: I want to assign my xml content to particular `div` and `ul` ? Sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to create dynamic `html`. Remove the inner `ul` and `li` and make them dynamic like below

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-block" id="sales_content"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var sales_date = $('#sales_date').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://www.xyz.co/AppData/sales_list.php',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

        var items = $(xml).find('sales_list').filter(function () {
            return $('sales_date', this).text() == sales_date;
        });

        var html = '';
        items.each(function (index, sales_list) {
            var id = $(this).find('id').text();
            var outlet_name = $(this).find('outlet_name').text();
            var sales_time = $(this).find('sales_time').text();

            html += '<ul><li class="item-content" id="sales_list"><div class="item-media">' + sales_time + '</div><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + outlet_name + '</div></div></li></ul>';
        });

        $('#sales_content').append(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Appending html is replicating data. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Nehil Mistry you can use `.remove()`  to remove existing `ul` before appending new like `$('#sales_content').find('ul').remove();`

Comment: Thanks. But I replaced append with html like `$('#sales_content').html(html);`

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the array before you do a foreach loop on it:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
   var aTime = $(a).find('sales_time').text();
   var bTime = $(b).find('sales_time').text();
   return (aTime == bTime) ? 0 : (aTime > bTime) ? 1 : -1;
}).each(function(index, sales_list){
    //Now that it's sorted, do stuff here:
    var id = $(this).find('id').text();
    var outlet_name = $(this).find('outlet_name').text();
    var sales_time = $(this).find('sales_time').text();
});
```